# laravel products orderByRaw COALESCE(discount_price, price), discount_price not defined

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-query-builder

```
    Product => id, name, price  
    Discount => id, percent, date_start, date_end  
    discount_products (Table) => product_id, discount_id 
    
    Product::addSelect(['discount_price' => function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('SUM(products.price * (100 - discounts.percent) / 100)')
            ->from('discounts')
            ->join('discount_products', 'discounts.id', '=', 'discount_products.discount_id')
            ->whereColumn('discount_products.product_id', 'products.id')
            ->where('date_start', '<=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
            ->where('date_end', '>=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->limit(1);
        }])
    //  ->orderByRaw('COALESCE(discount_price, price) ASC')     // not working
    //  ->orderByRaw('discount_price ASC')                      // working
    //  ->orderByRaw('price ASC')                               // working
        ->get();
```

Hello friends, firstly sorry for my english. I am using PostgreSQL as my  database.
I want to order products by their price.
If product has 'discount_price' use it or use the 'price' field. Please help.

Comment: It would be great if you could explain the query that you need.

Comment: I want order products by their price. but some products has discount

Comment: Please create sample data, and then show the output in the exact format that you need. Add all of this in the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Product::fromSub(function ($query) {
    $query->from("products")
        ->addSelect(['discount_price' => function ($query) {
            $query->selectRaw('SUM(products.price * (100 - discounts.percent) / 100)')
                ->from('discounts')
                ->join('discount_products', 'discounts.id', '=', 'discount_products.discount_id')
                ->whereColumn('discount_products.product_id', 'products.id')
                ->where('date_start', '<=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
                ->where('date_end', '>=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
                ->groupBy('id')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->limit(1);
        }]);
    }, 't')
    ->orderByRaw('COALESCE(discount_price, price) ASC')
    ->get();
```